# TCPClient read-write - how to keep in sync

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, irc

I have a basic IRC client which sends commands to the server. In the spec it says that the `PASS` command can have 2 numeric replies  `ERR_NEEDMOREPARAMS ERR_ALREADYREGISTRED`

When I send the command if the password is correct there will be no reply, but if it is incorrect I will get one of the two. But because my sending and recieving are independant, and async (using await-async) I have no reliable way at the moment of catching the error and stopping my send routine sending `NICK` and `USER` or any other commands.

**So my question is, what is a good way to tie up the read and write so I can stop when something goes wrong instantly, and generally keep tight control of the communication at any moment.**

Comment: When PASS is correct you get no reply, otherwise you get an error message, well,  I'd would wait with the Socket.poll() command a numbers of second before going on. If during that amount of second the socket is readable, has some data, it means you've got an answer, which implies it's a wrong PASS or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, one simple Synchronous Client Socket Example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class SynchronousSocketClient {

public static void StartClient() {
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.
    try {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

            // Release the socket.
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}",ane.ToString());
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ToString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
    }
}

public static int Main(String[] args) {
    StartClient();
    return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: How would this work if the server were to give no response, would it block forever?

Comment: this is the way to start a synchronous conversion, you can always create a loop to wait for the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to avoid sending `NICK` or `USER` until the `PASS` has been accepted or rejected - and as you point out, you can't actually know whether it's been accepted or not anyway.

You should simply send the `NICK`, `USER` and `PASS` commands with no delay, and then wait to see if one or any of them are rejected (in which case you'll get an error numeric) or all of them are accepted (in which case you'll get a `RPL_WELCOME` numeric).  There is no fixed order in which the registration commands need to be sent, so it doesn't matter if you have to re-send the `PASS` after you've already sent the `NICK` and `USER`, for example.